# Is multiple HttpAsyncClient's considered a bad practice?

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-httpcomponents

My application has to provide request "forwarding" mechanism, in a sense it processes incoming request and responds to it by retrieving data from one of "target" systems, determined based on the request.
This is implemented with a collection of HttpAsyncClient's, each of whom has its own configuration (MaxConnections, MaxPerRouteConnections etc.), according to the system it retrieves data from.

```
foreach (TargetSystem t: systems) {
        RequestConfig rc = RequestConfig.custom()
                .setConnectionRequestTimeout(s.timeout)
                .setConnectTimeout(s.timeout)
                .setSocketTimeout(s.timeout)
                .build();

        HttpAsyncClientBuilder b = HttpAsyncClients.custom()
                .setDefaultRequestConfig(rc)
                .setMaxConnTotal(t.maxConnections)
                .setMaxConnPerRoute(t.maxPerRouteConnections);

        t.client = b.build();
        t.client.start();
}
```

Then, I pick the right target client and use it for async HTTP request.
The question is, whether it's acceptable practice or only one HttpAsyncClient should be used for traffic between all target systems?
Currently, a number of threads (as the # of CPU's) are opened for each client, so for 10 targets, I end up with > 100 threads.
I want to limit max number of sockets to each system and to limit number of threads which serve each system (or all http-client outbound traffic altogether).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be only one instance of `HttpAsyncClient` per application or distinct service. Think of `HttpASyncClient` as a browser that can maintain multiple sessions / tabs

Comment: Thank you @oleg. How would you handle accessing certain targets through proxy? I currently call `setProxy` on the relevant `HttpAsyncClientBuilder`'s.  In regular browser it's supported out of the box by saying which *.subnet.net should skip proxy. How this should be done with `HttpAsyncClient`?

Comment: You can set different proxy for individual requests with RequestConfig or using a custom HttpRoutePlanner for individual routes